# Weird characters appear in ostream in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I have a program that should emulate a simple filesystem, I want to print the structure of directories, so I have overloaded the `<<` operator, and called another function that goes through my structure in rectursion. It works, BUT there are some weird hex values before some of the lines in the output. Is there something wrong with the way I manipulate iwth the `ostream` ? (I did not include the class definition, but it shouldnt matter)

Thanks all, for any answers!

```
std::ostream& printTree(std::ostream& os, const CFileSystem::TDir* x, int nmbTabs)
{
    int k;
    const CFileSystem::TDir * nxt = x;
    //cout << pocetTabu<<endl;
    while(nxt){
        os<<"--";
        for(k=0;k<nmbTabs;k++){
            os << '\t' ;
        }
        os<<"--";
        os << nxt->m_Name << endl;
        if(nxt->m_Sub){
            os << printTree(os,nxt->m_Sub,nmbTabs+1);
        }
        nxt=nxt->m_Next;
    }
    return os;
}
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const CFileSystem& x)
{
    os << "/" << endl;
    os << printTree(os, x.m_Root,1);
    return ( os );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
os << printTree(os, x.m_Root,1);
```

What is this?  `printTree` returns `std::ostream &`, and you're trying to output that (an ostream)?

That should be this:

```
printTree(os, x.m_Root,1);
```

That means, your `operator<<` should be implemented as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream & os, const CFileSystem & x)
{
    os << "/" << std::endl;
    return printTree(os, x.m_Root,1);
}
```

Comment: Oh my.. So the hex values were in fact the adresses of the ostream in memory, interesting  . Thanks so much!